# Find the set of all points such that $f$ is not locally bounded on them

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Definition :

Assume that $I$ is an interval.

A function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is locally bounded on $c \in I$ if there exist $\delta \gt 0$ and $M \gt 0$ such that :
$\forall x \in I \space \space \space   |x−c|\lt \delta⟹|f(x)|\le M$

Question :

Assume that for each natural number $k$ :

$f_k(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1-kx}  & \text{$0 \le x \le \frac{1}{k}$} \\
0 & \text{$ x \ge \frac{1}{k}$}
\end{cases}$

And Assume that $f$ is function such that for each $x$ in $[0,1]$:
 $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$

Notice that for each $x$ , there are finite number of non-zero terms in this summation.

Find the set of all points such that $f$ is not locally bounded on them.

Note : I have no idea about this question. I don't know how to find such a set for a general function. It would be nice if you provide a way to find such set for a given function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you have stated, only finitely many $n$'s are taken part in the summation $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}f_{n}(x)$ for each $x$ in $[0,1]$. If $x\ne 1/k$ for any $k$, then locally all the taken part functions $f_{n}$ are well behaved, when $x=1/k$, you can approach $x$ arbitrarily closed to the left of $1/k$, and $f(x)$ tends to infinity, so $f$ is not locally finite at $1/k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $x\in[0,1]$. If $x\ne1/k$ for any $k$, then choose some $\delta>0$ such that $1/k\notin(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for any $k$. Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n:1/n>x}f_{n}(x)$, but for any such $n$, $f_{n}$ has upper bound on $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, so is $f$ on that local neighbourhood.

If $x=1/k$ for some $k$, then for any $u\in(0,x)=(0,1/k)$, we have $f(u)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(u)\geq f_{k}(u)=\dfrac{1}{1-ku}$, so $f(u)\rightarrow\infty$ as $u\uparrow 1/k$, so $f$ is not bounded on any local neighbourhood at $1/k$.